# Am I using this script correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to using JavaScript. Am I using the following script correctly?

```js
function func() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block'
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none'
  if ("div1") {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block'
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none'
  }
  if ("div2") {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block'
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none'
  }
  if ("div3") {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home" func()="div1">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#SubmitNewRequest" func()="div2">Submit new request</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#SearchExisting" func()="div3">Search existing requests</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please format your code to be more readable. what exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to the site. I'm wondering if this code is written correctly.

Comment: The short answer, @codenoob, is that it is not. I'm working on an answer that addresses a good portion of the problems that it faces; hang tight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things:

- HTML tags have a name (such as 'a' or 'div') and may have attributes (such as 'id', 'href', etc). Attributes are key-value pairs (such as `id="croissant"` or `href="#head"`)
- Assuming that you're meaning for the user to click on a link to display/hide the div, you'd need to use the `onclick` attribute on the anchor element.

  ```
  # INCORRECT
  func()="div1"

  # CORRECT
  onclick="func('div1')"
  ```
- The `func` JavaScript function needs to take in a parameter so that you can send information to the function call (the name of the div, in this case)
- The if-statements within the JavaScript code should evaluate to boolean conditions: true or false.

Based on these, I've tweaked the code example you've given so that it works; click on "Run code snippet" to see it in action. This wouldn't necessarily be production-code, but this should better illustrate the different components that should be considered.

```js
function func(div) {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none'
  document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none'
  if (div == "div1") {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block'
  }
  if (div == "div2") {
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block'
  }
  if (div == "div3") {
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  display:none;
}
#div2 {
  display:none;
}
#div3 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home" onclick="func('div1')">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#SubmitNewRequest" onclick="func('div2')">Submit new request</a></li>
  <li><a href="#SearchExisting" onclick="func('div3')">Search existing requests</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="div1">Content A</div>
<div id="div2">Content B</div>
<div id="div3">Content C</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!